# 96 corolla: is there a way to break steering wheel lock with only minimal damage?

Tags: ignition, steering-wheel, steering-lock

Long story short - after diagnosing my 96 corolla with a blown head gasket (thanks to the members this community), it now needs to be moved to a final resting place where I will hack away at its insides in an attempt to replace the failing part.  Somehow, my mother in-law lost the spare key that I gave her and I must've left my copy at the nearby park because I can't find it.  No problem, I know the wiring set up do I basically hotwired my car.  It starts up fine, but after turning my wheel to pull away from the curb i suddenly felt my wheel lock...I put in back in park, tried turning it but it's locked as if the car is off. I understand that the ignition is what controls the lock (turn the key, unlock the wheel) but I don't want to tear it apart, though I'm close to getting a ticket if this thing isn't moved soon... Help!

Comment: So what do you need to accomplish? I haven't tried to do it, but I suspect that the steering lock is kind of hard to defeat since it is supposed to be an anti-theft device. Are you hoping that somebody has a way to do that or doe you have another question in mind? I think you know why it isn't disengaging :-)

Comment: Ahh yes.  I answered my own question in the description. Thanks!

Comment: Well if you're facing a ticket, getting it towed is probably less expensive. If you've got AAA  or towing insurance or the time to get it that is even a better solution. Failing that it looks like YouTube has lots of advice on hot-wiring and defeating steering locks…

Comment: Kind of a wild guess.  Remove the steering wheel cover, look at the connection to the lock cylinder and ignition switch, there should be some sort of rod there that controls the steering wheel lock.  You may need security bits.

Comment: Why bother taking anything apart? hammer a screw driver into the ignition cylinder and break it.